# How to Make Jenkins Pipeline wait for after each parallel job to be done

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-blueocean

because of the blue ocean view I want to do parallel steps. Is therethere a way to force QA to wait for  DEV to stop and then start. Only solution I found was using sleep, but I'm not sure how much first job will continue. Any advice would be nice !

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {

                    parallel(
                        DEV: {
                            sleep 5
                            echo 'DEV'
                        },                             

                        QA: {
                            sleep 6
                            echo 'QA'
                        }
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just place `dev` steps before `parallel`

Comment: But then I won't have this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/34926/blue-ocean-parallel-WORKS.png

Comment: put it into another parallel section (i never tried this)